# Impute missing data for one variable in longitudinal data set?

Tags: missing-data, multiple-imputation

I've got a longitudinal dataset with three variables: FIPS, eighteenplus, & year. FIPS is the id , and I'd like to impute data for eighteenplus.

Eighteenplus data were only available for 1990 and 2000, so I'd like to impute data for each FIPS-year in the period 1991-1999. However, I ran this code...

```
master_miced = mice(master, m=5, method = 'pmm', seed=14)
```

...which returned the below imputed values (a subset for one FIPS). The 1990 and 2000 values are 1,697,527 & 1,802,827 respectively, but the `mice` code returns values which are less by orders of magnitude in some cases.

```
FIPS    eighteenplus    year
36047   1697527         1990
36047   51728           1991
36047   25844           1992
36047   40584           1993
36047   3916            1994
36047   3606            1995
36047   35620           1996
36047   148214          1997
36047   46370           1998
36047   44641           1999
36047   1802827         2000
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong? This is my first time using `mice`. Seems the the predictive mean matching calculation is drawing from the dataset at large, not tailoring the calculation to each FIPS.

Comment: If the data are sequential, would it not make more sense to interpolate the missing values?

Comment: Thanks, Dan. That makes sense to me. Is there a package or command you'd recommend?

Comment: you haven't said what language you're using. I'm guessing R in which case I have no idea but I'm sure there is a popular standard one. You should decide if you want to do linear interpolation or something fancier like an [akima](http://www.alglib.net/interpolation/spline3.php#header5) spline. [Here is a comparison on MATLAB's methods](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html#input_argument_d119e519561) which should get you started in choosing, but the choice will depend on your data / problem I'm sure.

Comment: Yes, I'm using R. Thank you for the tip. I've downloaded akima and longitudinalData, and will perform a linear interpolation using the "longData" command.

Comment: It may be an issue with your missingness rate. In the example you have something like 85% missingness. I am not sure MICE can handle that. Also, I assume there is an iid assumption here when you use the MICE package, so it is not surprising that you are not getting values that look like interpolations.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is to impute time series data, I think you might try:

1. A specialized R package, such as [Amelia.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Amelia/index.html)
2. Casting the problem in state-space form, if it lends itself to such treatment and interpolate using the simulation smoother (see for instance `simulateSSM` in R package  `KFAS`). For the theory, [the book from Durbin-Koopman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/019964117X) is an excellent resource.

Comment: Thanks. I'm now running the amelia command, but receiving the following error message: "Error in vars > AMp : 
  comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types"

Comment: The comment seems to be fairly informative. Check the types of the variables compared, see why Amelia is unhappy with them.

Comment: Thanks. Made it past that error, and ran the amelia command. It's been executing for 60+ mins, and has returned the error message: "error: inv_sympd(): matrix is singular or not positive definite." Have you experienced this?

Comment: Probably some approximate linear dependence between the variables you are using. Try building your model step by step and rescaling variables.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind explaining what you mean by "building your model step by step"? And since the "eighteenplus" variable represents population, I'll plan to transform into log functional form.

Comment: I meant adding variables one or a few at a time. This way, you might detect which variable (or group of variables) introduces problems of rank deficiency in the matrix that the Amelia algorithm found to be singular or non positive definite.